# Pull image from another Docker Machine

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Is it possible to pull an image from another docker machine without having to install the docker repository?

I got 2 docker machines for development and i would like to deploy an image on the second docker machine that i have build with the first one.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "without having to install the docker repository".

Answer (score 3):

If you have created your docker servers using [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) then you could do an export/import using remote access to the docker agents on each server.

```
docker $(docker-machine config server1) export exampleimage:1.0 | docker $(docker-machine config server2) import - exampleimage:1.0
```

But....it would be a lot simpler to just rebuild the image on the second server, using the same Dockerfile.

Comment: Agree with Mark, building from the Dockerfile is better. The alternative is to run your own private registry, but this can be a bit overkill.